# Display Two <div>s Side-by-Side

Tags: html, css, css-float

My goal is to display two `<div>`s side-by-side with the content from both `<div>`s aligned at the top. I do not want long text in the second `<div>` to wrap underneath the first one.

Finally, I do not want to set the width of the second `<div>` because I need the markup to work in different widths.

Sample markup is below and at http://jsfiddle.net/rhEyM/.

**CSS**

```
.left-div {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: linen;
}
.right-div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 108px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-div">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="right-div">
    My requirements are <b>[A]</b> Content in the two divs should line
    up at the top, <b>[B]</b> Long text in right-div should not wrap
    underneath left-div, and <b>[C]</b> I do not want to specify a
    width of right-div. I don't want to set the width of right-div
    because this markup needs to work within different widths.
</div>
```

​

Comment: i have updated your **Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/rhEyM/10/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I removed the float from the second div to make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhEyM/2/

Comment: D'oh! You're exactly right. In my actual project, I wasn't setting the margin-left of the right div. That's all that's needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

Try to Use Flex as that is the new standard of html5.

http://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/1b431hxm/

```
<div id="row1">
    <div id="column1">I am column one</div>
    <div id="column2">I am column two</div>
</div>

#row1{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
justify-content: space-around;
}

#column1{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;

}


#column2{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the better solution, even if I know it does not work everytime (older Browsers and CSS3). But it gives you more flexibility concerning the height of the divs.

Answer (score 9):

**Try this :** (http://jsfiddle.net/TpqVx/)

```
.left-div {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    /*height: 20px;*/
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: linen;
}
.right-div {

    margin-left: 108px;
    background-color: lime;
}​​
```

---

```
<div class="left-div">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="right-div">
    My requirements are <b>[A]</b> Content in the two divs should line up at the top, <b>[B]</b> Long text in right-div should not wrap underneath left-div, and <b>[C]</b> I do not want to specify a width of right-div. I don't want to set the width of right-div because this markup needs to work within different widths.
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

***Hints :***

- Just use `float:left` in your left-most div **only**.
- No real reason to use `height`, but anyway...
- Good practice to use `<div 'clear:both'>&nbsp;</div>` after your last div.

Comment: Any reason why 'clear:both' has to be used after last div? (Why is this a good practice?)